# RTSP Stream into OpenCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv, streaming, rtsp

For a school project my partner and I are trying to push video from an android tablet (Nexus 7) to a server (as an ip webcam), pull from the server into OpenCV 2.4.6, process that, send it back to a server, and have the tablet display the feed in real or near-real time.

We arent using opencv for android because the goal is for a remote user to decide how to process the video (i.e. selecting a template to match or something from the stream).

Our question is this: we have managed to get the android webcam stream onto a server as an h264 rtsp stream.  All the documentation for how to pull an rtsp stream is either outdated, really confusing, or altogether non-existent.  We tried using a VideoCapture object and then tried using cvCreateFileCapture but neither seem to be working.  How do we do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project that does precisely this combination.

1. Android generating the content from front or rear camera
2. RTSP protocol for streaming
3. h264

https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/

Comment: We tried spydroid but it wasn't working for some reason.  My partner found a work around in another open source file that esentially opens the camera and on the computer end we run a continuous loop to pull jpegs from the smartphone.  It isn't ideal in terms of fps (so it is a bit choppy) but it runs at near-real time and does what we need it to.